# Is there any method or something else for listen incoming phone calls using ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic4

Is there any way to listen to incoming phone calls or run an event or alert when receiving phone calls using ionic.

i tried this code:

```
document.addEventListener.on('receiveCall', (c: any) => {
  var call = c.data;
  alert("receivev call: " +JSON.stringify(call));
})
```

this code is not working. help, please.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the following Cordova plugin to your Ionic application: [Cordova-Call-Trap](https://github.com/renanoliveira/cordova-phone-call-trap). Bear in mind that this works for Android only, don't think there is an iOS version of the Cordova plugin.

And then use the following call:

```
PhoneCallTrap.onCall(function(state) {
    console.log("CHANGE STATE: " + state);

    switch (state) {
        case "RINGING":
            console.log("Phone is ringing");
            break;
        case "OFFHOOK":
            console.log("Phone is off-hook");
            break;

        case "IDLE":
            console.log("Phone is idle");
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: I already tried this working well but i want to get caller data.

Comment: Looking at the source code, you should be able to get the telephone number. https://github.com/renanoliveira/cordova-phone-call-trap/blob/master/src/android/PhoneCallTrap.java#L44

Comment: well thanks for reply, this is working. But based on this code i am unable to get number